# How to work with distributions that are discrete in some variables and continuous in others?

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study

[image]

So, in this problem I am asked to find the cumulative distribution of the continuous variable T and the probability that $J=3$ given T is larger than 10 and lastly the conditional expectation of T given $j=2.$ I have tried just adding the pdf but they do not have the same range? Any idea what to do?

Comment: Think of all three components as having a common domain of $(-\infty, \infty):$ now you can compute their integrals and sum them without difficulty.

Comment: Do you have any weights? Do you consider the mixture to be $\sum_{j=1}^3w_j\cdot f_{T,J}$?

Comment: @KarelMacek: the weights are already included in the $f(t,j)$'s.

Comment: @whuber, but that is the thing like the domains are not the same, can I still add them?

Comment: If it helps, express $f$ in terms of indicator functions as the sum $$f(t,j)=\frac{t}{150}I(0\le t\le 5)I(j=1) + \frac{t}{300}I(0\le t \le 10)I(j=2) + \frac{t}{216}I(0\le t\le 18)I(j=3).$$ Then apply the definitions.  For instance, the CDF of $T$ is obtained by computing $\Pr(T\le t)$ for arbitrary values of $t.$ The formulation of $f$ suggests considering five cases: $t\lt 0,$ $0\le t \le 5,$ $5\lt t \le 10,$ $10\lt t\le 18,$ and $t\gt 18.$  The first and last are trivial when you assume $f$ describes a distribution, but are worth checking nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

As many comments pointed out, the information given by "$f(t, j)$" needs more clarification, because it is neither a simple pdf/pmf nor a standard representation of mixture model.  My interpretation to $f(t, j)$ is that it characterizes the joint distribution of the random vector $(T, J)$ in a way such that (in particular, you should NOT interpret $f(t, j)$ as the conditional density of $T$ given $J = j$, as $\int_\mathbb{R} f(t, j)dt < 1$ for all $j$).
\begin{align}
& F_1(t) := P[T \leq t, J = 1] = 
\begin{cases}
0 & t < 0, \\
\int_0^t f(x, 1)dx = \frac{1}{300}t^2 & 0 \leq t < 5, \\
\frac{1}{12} & t \geq 5.
\end{cases} \\
& F_2(t) := P[T \leq t, J = 2] = 
\begin{cases}
0 & t < 0, \\
\int_0^t f(x, 2)dx = \frac{1}{600}t^2 & 0 \leq t < 10, \\
\frac{1}{6} & t \geq 10.
\end{cases} \\
& F_3(t) := P[T \leq t, J = 3] = 
\begin{cases}
0 & t < 0, \\
\int_0^t f(x, 3)dx = \frac{1}{432}t^2 & 0 \leq t < 18, \\
\frac{3}{4} & t \geq 18.
\end{cases} \\
\end{align}

It can be verified that for $t \geq 18, F_1(t) + F_2(t) + F_3(t) = P[T \leq t] = 1$, therefore, this interpretation, i.e.,
\begin{align}
f(t, j) = \frac{dP[T \leq t, J = j]}{dt}
\end{align}
indeed allows for a valid marginal distribution of $T$.  In the literature, $F_j(t)$ are sometimes referred to as "sub-distribution function".  The marginal distribution function of $T$ now can be obtained by adding $F_j(t)$:
\begin{align}
F(t) := P[T \leq t] = 
\begin{cases}
0 & t < 0, \\
\frac{79}{10800}t^2 & 0 \leq t < 5, \\
\frac{1}{12} + \frac{43}{10800}t^2 & 5 \leq t < 10, \\
\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{432}t^2 & 10 \leq t < 18, \\
1  & t \geq 18.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

I will leave the remaining two calculations ($P[J = 3 | T > 10]$ and $E[T | J = 2]$) back to yourself, which are not hard to derive based on the above discussion.  You shall also try to recover the standard representation of $F(t)$ in terms of a mixture model, i.e., try to write $F(t)$ as
\begin{align}
F(t) = p_1 P[T \leq t | J = 1] + p_2 P[T \leq t | J = 2] + p_3 P[T \leq t | J = 3],
\end{align}
where $p_j = P[J = j], j = 1, 2, 3$.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am still not 100% how you got the fraction 43/10800. But with that info, are we able to find the marginal pdf and cdf of j alone? Thanks

Comment: @Cristian I may have made some calculation error, but $43/10800$ is supposed to be $1/600 + 1/432$ (you need to choose what to add depending on $t$'s domain).  For the latter question, of course yes.  Actually it has already been shown in the answer that $P[J = 1] = 1/12, P[J = 2] = 1/6, P[J = 3] = 3/4$.